# How to display all the lines of a file in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

So as the title says, I want to display all the content of the file in the edit box but I dont know how to do that

this is the handler of the button, when pressed it will make the user choose a file and its content is supposed to appear in the edit box.
The problem is that its only showing the first line somehow

```
UpdateData(TRUE);
CFileDialog Dlg(TRUE);
int iRet = Dlg.DoModal();
CString StrFileName = Dlg.GetPathName();

if (iRet == IDOK) 
{
        CStdioFile file;
        file.Open(StrFileName, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeText);

        file.ReadString(m_strEditCtrl);
        file.Close();
        UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: ReadString reads a single line of text. [http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?71104-How-to-read-the-whole-text-in-a-CStdioFile-into-a-CString](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?71104-How-to-read-the-whole-text-in-a-CStdioFile-into-a-CString) should help

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/mfc/reference/cstdiofile-class#readstring), the `ReadString()` method reads just a single line of text.

Comment: If you want to display the whole file, why are you only reading the first line? Did you read the MSDN page for `CStdioFile::ReadString`? BTW, you might also want to consider [EM_STREAMIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-streamin).

Comment: Have you used `std::fstream` to open and `std::getline` to read from the file?  You don't always need the MFC functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use MFC for you application needs, only us it as UI. All of your code should be written in a portable fashion. IMHO.

Write global, non MFC functions for your needs. So, to get the string from a file.

```
std::string read_file(const std::wstring& filepathname)
{
    std::ifstream is(filepathname, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    auto buf_size = is.tellg();
    if (buf_size == -1)
        return std::string();

    std::string str;
    str.resize(buf_size);
    is.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    is.read(str.data(), str.size());
    return str;
}
```

Now for the properties of your CEdit box, you must set `Multiline` to true if you want to display lines that end with `\r\n`. You may also want to enable `Vertical Scroll` and `Horizontal Scroll`.

Create a `control variable` and set the text directly with it. You can do that with the wizard. It is almost always a mistake to use `UpdateData`. It defeats the purpose of data exchange in a dialog.

So, you have declared:

```
CEdit cEditCtrl;
```

and you can:

```
auto str = read_file("filename.txt");
cEditCtrl.SetWindowText(str.c_str());
```

Now, I did this as if you have  multi_byte set instead of Unicode. I strongly recomend that if don't have Uncode set, do it. From experiance, much easier to do sooner than later. In that case if you read an ASCII file, you would have some globals like:

```
inline std::wstring to_wide(const char* ps) { return std::wstring(boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(ps)); }
inline std::wstring to_wide(const std::string& str) { return to_wide(str.c_str()); }
```

You can do this with the std library instead of boost. Then you can:

```
cEditCtrl.SetWindowText(to_wide(str).c_str());
```

I would add, that as long as you compile Unicode, you can dispense with that macro: `_T("text")` and just write `L"text"` for literals.

Comment: If you read an ASCII file you don't need any sort of advanced transcoding. ASCII is valid UTF-8, and (when every code unit is appropriately widened) UTF-16 and UTF-32. ASCII isn't where character encoding is a problem that doesn't have a trivial encoding. That's reserved for non-ASCII text data.

Answer (score 2):

The return value is either NULL or False, when end of file is reached.

So you can loop for each line. The pseudocode (Not tested. May have issues.) looks somewhat below.

```
CString eachString;

while (file.ReadString(eachString))
{
    m_strEditCtrl += eachString;

    //The CString version of this function removes the '\n' if present; the LPTSTR version does not.

    m_strEditCtrl += "\n";
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this because you stuck to the platform MFC with a simple solution.